# Displaying the name variable in field for three characters longer than name

Tags: c

## C

Question as this way as in the title.
How to display the string variable in field for three characters longer than length of this variable.

code:

```
char name[10];
int length;

printf("Enter your name: ");
scanf("%s", name);
length = strlen(name) + 3;
```

And what then?

It should be something like that:

```
Enter your name: 
XXX
"   XXX"
```

Comment: Print three spaces, then the name?

Comment: I meant whether there is some special specifier in printf() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to simply add 3 spaces before the `%s`:

```
printf("   %s\n", name);
```

You can also use a variable length specifier (if you want to learn how it works):

```
printf("%*s\n", length+3, name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use printf with a variable length specifier:

```
printf("%*s", length + 3, name);
```